# identifying the type of clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Consider this sentence, please:

1. *That was my first time **driving a car***.

What type of clause is "**driving a car**"? Is it a reduced relative clause, gerund clause, or an adverbial participle clause?

Comment: "Driving a car" is a gerund-participial clause, functioning as an adjunct.

Comment: Contrast 'That was my first cousin driving a car.'

Comment: @BillJ I'm curious. How can an adjunct, which by definition is adverbial, modify a noun? I see it can be an adjunct in a sentence like "I had an exciting time driving a car," but in OP's example "driving a car" seems to modify "time" as if it were an apposition: "my first time (of) driving a car." I can also think of "experience" functioning in the same way: That was my first experience (of) driving the car. I wrote (of) just to show the relationship between the noun and the gerund, as it wouldn't be idiomatic to actually use that preposition.

Comment: @Gustavson It's not modifying "time", since gerund-participial clauses as modifiers of nouns are semantically similar to relative clauses, which is not the case here. And it's not, of course, a complement, so it can only be an adjunct.

Comment: It's a gerund phrase (traditional grammar). *Driving a car is fun. That was my first time driving a car.* I agree with @Gustavson that it seems to be the object of a deleted preposition, and it modifies *time*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat No, there is no deleted preposition, and it doesn't modify "time". I explained why in my last comment. It's simply an adjunct in clause structure.